How to solve the "No directory provided for file keyring" issue while integreting stripe CLI to a project using Ubuntu WSL on windows?
I am working on a SaaS project using the Wasp Boiler framework and attempting to integrate Stripe CLI. Despite following all the setup steps, including downloading the Stripe CLI and configuring the necessary files, I am unable to get the CLI to authenticate and forward events as expected. The CLI prompts for login and provides a pairing code, but the process does not complete successfully even after authorizing access. When I authorize access via the link, I get "No directory provided for file keyring".
No directory provided for file keyring issue
I followed the instructions in a YouTube tutorial that demonstrated the Stripe CLI integration. Here is a minimal reproducible example of what I have tried:
1.Download and Extract Stripe CLI:
wget https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/download/v1.20.0/stripe_1.20.0_linux_x86_64.tar.gztar -xvf stripe_1.20.0_linux_x86_64.tar.gz
2.Move Stripe CLI to the Appropriate Directory:
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/
sudo mv stripe /usr/local/bin/
3.Verify Installation:stripe --version
# Output: stripe version 1.20.0
4.Attempt to Listen for Webhook Events:
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3001/stripe-webhook
# Output: You have not configured API keys yet.
Running `stripe login`...
# Your pairing code is: cute-assure-love-honor
# This pairing code verifies your authentication with Stripe.
# To authenticate with Stripe, please go to: https://dashboard.stripe.com/stripecli/confirm_auth?t=yuztLSWQsdeijscmN71VzyN4t0kJUapF
# ⣻ Waiting for confirmation...
5.Authorize the Pairing Code in Browser:
I followed the link, confirmed the pairing code, and authorized access.Check Configuration:stripe config --list
# Output: open /home/fidele_ubuntu/.config/stripe/config.toml: no such file or directory
Expected Result: After authorizing the pairing code, I expected the CLI to authenticate and start listening for webhook events to forward to my local server.
Actual Result: The CLI keeps waiting for confirmation and does not proceed to listen for webhook events.

It looks like there is an open issue with this here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/933#issuecomment-2172772839
Other users reporting problems with 1.20.0 are finding success downgrading to 1.19.5 for now. I'd suggest adding your report there and temporarily downgrading.
